# Help coding an Abelian Sandpile

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, programming, physics, recursion

I'm attempting to code an [abelian sandpile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model). I thought a good way to go about it would be utilizing recursion, which I've never tried in MMA before. The code currently runs but doesn't seem to work (it does not appear to be converging towards a stable configuration), and I can't go to very large system sizes due to bumping up against the recursion limit, and I have problems if I increase the recursion limit too much. Any and all suggestions appreciated, this is a project for fun, feel free to do what you like with the code.

```
L = 100;
$RecursionLimit = 10000;
sandpile = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {L, L}]; (*initial configuration*)
neighbors = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};

(*this function checks if site (x,y) has exceeded its capacity
  If so, the grains are distributed to neighboring sites and then
  they are checked recursively for excess capacity*)

pile[x_, y_] := Module[{xp, yp},
  If[
   sandpile[[x, y]] > 4
   ,
   sandpile[[x, y]] -= 4;
   Do[{xp, yp} = {x, y} + neighbors[[i]]; If[0 < xp <= L && 0 < yp <= L, sandpile[[xp, yp]] += 1;], {i, 4}];
   Do[{xp, yp} = {x, y} + neighbors[[i]]; If[0 < xp <= L && 0 < yp <= L, pile[xp, yp]], {i, 4}]; (*note recursion*)
   ]
  ]

nmax = 100000;
m = 0;

Monitor[
 Do[
   {x, y} = RandomInteger[{1, L}, {2}]; (*pick a random site*)
   sandpile[[x, y]] += 1; (*add a single grain*)
   pile[x, y]; (*check for excess capacity and trigger avalanche*)
   m++;
   , {n, nmax}]; 
 ,
 ArrayPlot[sandpile, PlotLabel -> "Iteration " <> ToString[m], ImageSize -> Medium]
 ]
```

Comment: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1927307

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, although this is just a C++ code which does the calculation and then using Mathematica for the plot :)

Comment: Interesting! It looks like you could maybe try moving the call to pile to outside pile itself and control the looping some other way, like with a While loop or something. Also in general you might find it better to map over lists with `/@` in certain spots instead of setting up all these `Do`s! One advantage that has is that it's amenable to parallelization!

Comment: It also might be useful to conceptualize the process in stages that are slightly different to the ones being implemented here. So, `pile` essentially is depth-first: as it goes through the neighbors of `{x,y}`, it calculates all the consequences of the first over-capacity neighbor it encounters before moving on to the next neighbor. Instead, it might help to essentially do it breadth-first: calculate the one-step effects of *all* the neighbors first, before calculating the knock-on effects of the cells the neighbors have affected. This might ease the recursion depth problem!

Comment: @thorimur thanks, yes I believe this is actually the issue with the code, the recursive method that I am using actually is not the same as the original algorithm, it should be breadth-first as you say, each pile should be toppled before re-checking for new over-capacity piles

Answer (score 11):

The code below replaces `pile` with a function `avalanche` that works a bit bit differently! Instead of calling itself, it outputs a list of things that we then want to recursively call `avalanche` on again. When the list is empty (there are no more things to compute), we stop. To implement the recursion, we use `NestWhile[f, init, testfunction]`.

#### the `avalanche` function

Here `f` isn't precisely `avalanche`, but let's first detail exactly what `avalanche` does:

- On an argument `{x, y}`, it checks if `sandpile[[x,y]]` is over capacity, and if so, reduces it by four: `sandpile[[x,y]] -= 4`.
- Forms the neighbors of `{x,y}` by, via `makeneighbors`*, giving us a list of neighbors `{x,y} + r` for every `r` in `neighbors` (except those that wind up the grid). (See `makeneighbors` at the bottom for that function's implementation.)
- Replaces each of these elements (at level 1 only; that's the `{1}` that is the last argument to `Replace`) with itself if iterating the sandpile at that spot is over capacity, and delete it (replace it with `Nothing`) otherwise. There's maybe a better way of doing this, but this was the first (well, second; the first idea didn't work, actually!) that came to mind. This is weird, because it actually performs the iteration of a spot in `sandpile` *by executing the test*. So, this is probably Bad Code, but hey, kinda cool that you can do that!

So, the overall behavior of `avalanche` is: take in a point `{x,y}`, perform updating of `sandpile` for it and its neighbors, return the list of neighbors that are now over capacity.

#### building the function for `NestWhile` out of `avalanche`

We now want a function `f` in `NestWhile` that takes in a list of such over-capacity neighbors, does `avalanche` on each of them, and smushes together all the resulting lists of over-capacity positions into one list of positions, deleting duplicates.

`#` is our stand-in for the list of neighbors as we build this anonymous function. To do avalanche on each of the elements of the list, we can do `avalanche /@ #`. The result is a list of lists of positions.

`Union` can then do the, er, set union, as you might expect, but it takes in arguments as `Union[list1, list 2, ...]`. We have `{list1, list2, ...}`. So we need to replace the head of this (which is `List`: `{a, b, ...}` is just `List[la, b, ...]`) with `Union`. We do that by `Union @@`, giving us the overall function `(Union @@ (avalanche /@ #)) &` that we use in `NestWhile`.

Note that `g /@ {}` is `{}`, and `Union @@ {}` is `Union[]` is `{}`, so eventually, when no points are over capacity, we will have `{}` as output, and we want to stop the loop. So our `testfunction` ought to check if the output is `{}`, i.e. `# == {} &`.

We want to start the `NestWhile` on just one point—or, more precisely, the list containing one point, since we always expect the input/output in `NestWhile` to be a list of points. Hence `{{x,y}}`.

So, that's that for the actual function behavior!

#### visualization

Here's how the visualization works: we decide we want to pause for a tenth of a second each time we go through the `NestWhile` loop at least *twice*. (The way the current code is, we go through once every time. It might help to change that by moving the check for sandpile capacity via `sandpile[[x,y]]` outside the function `avalanche` and outside the whole loop, so we never enter the loop if we don't need to. But I didn't do that here to keep it close to the original code.)

One way we can do this is by having a virtual switch `p` which is `1` before we've executed the function in `NestWhile`, but gets flipped off once we go throuh the `NestWhile` loop, *after we've checked*. So we make `p = 1` in every `Do` iteration, and before executing our function `f`, we check if `p` has been flipped to `0` yet. If `p` has been flipped, we pause for `0.1` seconds. If not, it's the first time through, and we don't pause, and instead just flip `p` to `0`. After all this we execute our usual function. So our function has gone from `f` as above to `If[p == 0, Pause[0.1], p = 0]; f`. Here, though, we also want to check that we've passed iteration `15000`, since the first avalanches are very small and not very interesting to watch. So we add the check `m > 15000` to get `If[p == 0 && m > 15000, Pause[0.1], p = 1]; f`

(Note: I just realized this isn't the `Do` loop variable! The variable `n` (given `{n,nmax}`) already keeps track of the iteration of the `Do` loop for us. So we could have just used `n` instead of `m`.)

For colors, we just set `ColorFunction` in `ArrayPlot` to something that's gray below or at 4, and magenta above. We also need to turn off `ColorFunctionScaling` otherwise all values will be scaled to lie between 0 and 1 before we apply the color function, but we want our color function to take in raw values.

#### *`makeneighbors`

Named this function for convenience! Taking in a point `{x,y}`, it maps the function `({x,y} + #) &` over the list of `neighbors` via `/@`.

It then selects from this list the ones that have each component lying in the appropriate bounds, by applying `AllTrue[#, 1 <= # <= L &] &` to test them. (Note that the first `#` will be filled by the neighboring point itself as a list of coordinates, whereas the second represents a component *of* that list of coordinates.) This gives us a list containing `{x,y} + r` for every element `r` of `neighbors`, without the ones that lie outside the grid.

```
L = 100;
neighbors = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};

(*Make the neighbors that satisfy the bounding constraints in all of
their (2) components*)
makeneighbors[{x_, y_}, L_] := 
 Select[({x, y} + #) & /@ neighbors, AllTrue[#, (1 <= # <= L &)] &];

(*This replaces the pile function. We want avalanche to 1) have the side-effect of
modifying all the neighbor cells and 2) return a list of those
neighbors which are now over capacity. When we use this function,
we'll want to map it back over all of its outputs via a NestWhile.
(Note that we could move the first check of capacity out of the
function, as it's kind of redundant.) *)
avalanche[{x_, 
   y_}] :=
 If[
  sandpile[[x, y]] > 4,
  sandpile[[x, y]] -= 4;

  (*generate the neighbors, 
    then keep the ones that became over capacity after incrementing
    them; delete the ones that don't become over capacity. Note that the
    increment happens inside the test, which is kind of weird! (Also, ++x is
    the one that returns the new value of x (as opposed to x++), so we really are
    testing the new value.) So, the function avalanche returns a list of newly "hot"
    or "precarious" points.*)
  Replace[makeneighbors[{x, y}, L], {a_, b_} :> 
    If[++(sandpile[[a, b]]) > 4, {a, b}, Nothing], {1}],
(*If it wasn't over capacity, just return the empty list, as there are no "hot" points.*)
  {}
  ];

nmax = 100000;
m = 0;
sandpile = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {L, L}];
Monitor[Do[{x, y} = RandomInteger[{1, L}, {2}];
  (*indicate that we're on a new iteration, 
  and haven't triggered any avalanches yet (for visualization purposes)*)
  p = 1;
  (*add a grain to our random site*)
  sandpile[[x, y]] += 1;
  NestWhile[(
     (*If we've evaluated the function at least once already, 
       and we're past the 15000th evaluation (skipping ahead because
       it starts out kind of uneventful), pause for 0.1 second for
       visualization purposes, so we can "see" the avalanche play out.*)
        If[p == 0 && m > 15000,
           Pause[.1],
           (*Indicate that after this point, 
             the function has been evaluated once this iteration by
             "flipping p to 0"*)
            p = 0];

  (*trigger avalanche on the set of over-capacity points,
    starting with just the set containing the newly-incremented point,
    then aggregate the resulting list of lists of "hot" points into one
    list with no duplicates*)

    Union @@ (avalanche /@ #)) &, {{x, y}}, (# != {} &)];

  m++;,{n, nmax}];
(*Output the final arrayplot from Monitor at the end*) 
 ArrayPlot[sandpile, PlotLabel -> "Iteration " <> ToString[m], 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[# <= 4, GrayLevel[#/4], Magenta] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False],

 ArrayPlot[sandpile, PlotLabel -> "Iteration " <> ToString[m], 
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  (*Color all values by graylevel between 0 and four (0 - black, 4 - white)
    and color over-capacity values in magenta.*) 
  ColorFunction -> (If[# <= 4, GrayLevel[#/4], Magenta] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]]
```

P.S. I should be sleeping, but I made a gif of it... :)

[image: animation of abelian sandpile on 2D grid highlighting avalanches]

Comment: very nice! I will look through it. I realized that the way that my original code works using recursion is actually not how the algorithm is supposed to operate (I think it causes it to become non-abelian), I'll be working on this for fun as well, thanks for losing sleep over it though :P

Comment: out of curiosity, did you make the gif in MMA?

Comment: Yes, I did! I used `Sow` and `Reap`. I inserted `If[m>16050,Sow,#&]@`before the monitored `ArrayPlot`, which `Sow`ed the values given by Monitor whenever we were past the 16050'th iteration, and applied the identity function otherwise. I then enclosed the whole thing in `Reap`, set `nmax` to 16100 so that the `Do` actually finished, and the list of gif frames I used could then be extracted from the output of `Reap`! I then did `Export["filename.gif",listofframes,"DisplayDurations"->0.1,AnimationRepetitions->Infinity]`. Then I compressed it in an online tool, cuz MMA makes MASSIVE gifs. :)

Comment: Okay, I edited it with a summary of what the code does! Lmk if any part is unclear! :)

Comment: thanks, very helpful, I'm curious did you ever get it to produce interesting outputs? I originally thought that the algorithm should converge to the identity, but I don't think that's actually the case

Comment: No, I haven't, even when letting it run for a while...however, from the wikipedia article, I found "A popular special case of this model is given when the initial configuration is zero for all vertices except the origin." So maybe starting with `sandpile=PadLeft[{{}},{L,L}];` (`L`x`L`, all zeros) `sandpile[[L/2,L/2]]=a0` for a large `a0` (and even `L`, ofc) would produce something interesting? I'm gonna go try that now...

Comment: Edit: that should be `PadLeft[{{}},{L-1,L-1}]` to center the origin. (This also relies on only repeatedly toppling that point, and not choosing a random spot each time. So `{x,y}` is always `{L/2,L/2}`, and we don't `+=1` sandpile)

Comment: Edit to the edit: that should be `(L+1)/2` with odd `L` to center the origin!